# Is there a timer on available Garrison missions?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to figure out if I should wait and level up my followers for a better % chance at completing this rare item mission or if it will expire.

When do garrison missions expire, and get removed from the list of available missions?

Comment: Yes, missions do expire if not attempted within a certain time frame. The timer seems to be different, depending on the rarity of the mission. It is somewhere between 48-96 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they do.

But there doesn't seem to be a general rule of when missions expire, I personally experienced that some missions expired after 2 days, but people over the internet are [arguing](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/15354715644) about how long it takes to expire. After checking in-game I also did some research but there's actually **no expire date displayed in-game**. This makes some people think that the expiring of missions might be a bug, but there's no official statement from Blizzard about that.

Answer (score 0):

The [Master Plan](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/master-plan) addon has a timer built in that knows or takes an educated guess on how long you've had the mission and compares it to the average time it takes for a mission of that type to disappear. So far from my experience, it seems to be accurate.